# Firebase Database childs sorting

Tags: android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

As normally all childs and all Values are sorted alphabetical on the Firebase Server. 
Is it possible to get new childs always on bottom of the Firebase list?
I want to archive them by the Creation Date. The old ones should always stay on top and the new uploaded childs should always added at them bottom.
The date itself does not matter, but the new children always have to be hung at the bottom. Is this possible?

```
My structure: FIREBASE --> Events ---> Party1 name ---> some details
                                  ---> Party2 name ---> some details
                                  ---> Party3 name---> some details
```

So when I upload now "Party4 name" and its name has a letter between Party1 and Party3 it comes between them. But I want that all new childs are always coming at the bottom.

Comment: Which kind of structure do you try to create there? You can always create a new key for a value or object in firebase, which automatically, as you said, is alphabetically sorted. (databaseReference.push(..))

Comment: If so, you have multiple options. Either create an event object, give it a key via push and there is your sorting. Moreover you can give the object a timestamp (inverted) and sort by childvalue.

Comment: I have updated the question with the structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend a structure like this.

### 1. You have to think about some type of Event object.

In my example it has the values `name`, `time` and `guestCount`.

### 2. Every time there is a new Event, you make push onto your database reference

With android *firebase-sdk* you can make a push on the `yourdatabase/events` route,
with `databaseReference.push().getKey();` -> wich will create a new **key** for you event object.

### 3. Upload the new event object to your database

Use this key, that you have generated from step 2 above and push your newly created
object underneath `yourdatabase/events/key`. You can either use `databaseReference.push()` for single values
or, as I recommend, use `databaseReference.updateChildren(<hashmap>);` to upload all your values in an **atomic** way into the database.

This will result in a database structure looking likes this:

```
{
  "events": {
    "abc" : {
      "name" : "party 1",
      "time" : "-0034534535345",
      "guestCount" : 64
    },
    "abd" : {
      "name" : "party 2",
      "time" : "-0034534535345",
      "guestCount" : 128
    },
    "abe" : {
      "name" : "party 3",
      "time" : "-456456456456",
      "guestCount" : 16
    }
  }
}
```

The new keys from step 2 and 3 are now sorted and a new event will always be at the bottom of the list. Via the timestamp it is also possible to use a firebase-database query and sort by childvalue.

> The unique key generated by push() is based on a timestamp, so list items are automatically ordered chronologically.

Check stackoverflow and google, why I have inverted the timestamp. 
Firebase queries all your new objects lexicographically in ascending order.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

I just suggest you a structure only for impleminting the sort operation 
`Unique key` by

> String uniqueKey= ref.push().getKey()

```
My structure: FIREBASE --> Events ---> UniqueKey1---> Party1 name+some details+ UniqueKey1
                                  ---> UniqueKey2---> Party2 name+some details+ UniqueKey2
                                  ---> UniqueKey3---> Party3 name+some details+ UniqueKey3
```